# Click on List view in Side drawer layout not reponding

Tags: android

I have implemented side drawer layout with a list view. If i click on list view item I am not getting any response no log or no toast. I don't know where I did wrong. I am stuck with this issue from two days. Can some one help me out solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Below is the XML code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/newmapsactivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="gmaps.hornok.driverhornok.view.activity.NewMapsActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">




            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/opensidenav_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_backnewbutton"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/sidemore" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffffff">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profilelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="148dp"
                android:background="#5ec0cb">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/driver_image"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/oval"
                    android:elevation="1dp" />

                <com.daniribalbert.customfontlib.views.CustomFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driver_image"
                    android:text="Driver name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    app:font="gotham_medium_webfont" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profilelayout"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:divider="@null" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java Code :

```
    SideDrawerlistAdpater drawerlistAdpater = new SideDrawerlistAdpater(SideNavigationDrawer.this, titles, icons);
            listview.setAdapter(drawerlistAdpater);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"get poisition" +position);

                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });

public void selectItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewMapsActivity.this, DriverEarningsTabbedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(NewMapsActivity.this, Subscriptions.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: why you put listview inside drawerlayout ? how's your drawers UI ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you !

Comment: attach your navigationdrawer image that you made .

Comment: I have set Images and titles to listview

Comment: you want to make drawer look like this ? https://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/android-navigation-drawer-activity.png

Comment: Yes, similar to that.

Comment: then your implementing drawer wrong. there is no need to add listview in Drawerlayout

Comment: should I do with menu items ?

Comment: I have a single group .

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution ..

in your XML code ..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="#f1ecec"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

inside your `@menu/activity_main_drawer`  ..  apply this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_aboutus"
        android:title="About US" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_portfolio"
        android:title="Portfolio" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_career"
        android:title="Career" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_services"
        android:title="Services" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
        android:title="Contact" />


</menu>
```

so it will solved your problem . if you need detail explanation . than you can visit .

[Navigation Drawer](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Can you send me the example link.

Comment: i attached it ,, you can visit it

Comment: Thank you! I will implement

Comment: if your problem is solved . you can accept this answer . so we can close topic